# Can we use Linq with View of sql server?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, view

As per my understanding Views could improve performance and I intend to use Views in my database and because my database is huge, I want to create the views for different queries. Is there any way to access the Views in .Net Windows applications or can we use LINQ with Views? What is the exact way to use View in .Net, so that i can improve performance? I am writing a C# desktop application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I want to create a view in sql server database that must have the Where clause. and when i will drag it to .Net dbml file, and use some where then must ask the parameter. can this possible."*

I ***think*** you are asking if you can pass a "where" parameter to the View when it is called. This is not possible, but you *can* pass parameters to a Stored Procedure. Also, your stored procedure can query the View and use the param to filter it down. Here's an example:

VIEW: named "PersonView" -- gives you everything (no Where clause)

```
SELECT     cit.CitizenID, cit.FirstName, cit.LastName, cit.OrganizationID, org.Name AS 'OrganizationName', 
FROM   Citizens AS cit JOIN Organizations AS org ON cit.OrganizationID = org.ID
```

STORED PROCEDURE: named "spPersonQuery" -- does your Where clause

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTest]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @orgID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * from dbo.PersonView as ps
    where ps.OrganizationID = @orgID
END
GO
```

You can then drag your Stored Procedure into your DBML file and when you call it, you will pass in the int param "orgID".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just drag the View from server explorer in visual studio onto your linq2sql database model.

Comment: Thanks. But can i use query specific View on single table ? means i want to use Where condition in View. can i use ? and can i pass the parameter to that view ? i am new in Database side .

Comment: Yes, I think you would just want to execute a linq query against the view. The answer from Chris Hogan shows an example linq statement. However you would need to add a where clause depending on the exact data you wish to get. Microsoft have plenty of linq samples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688084

Comment: thanks again. in fact I want to create a view in sql server database that must have the Where clause. and when i will drag it to .Net dbml file, and use some where then must ask the parameter. can this possible. I am aware about the clauses in Linq. but not sure about can i use clauses in Create View statement.please guide more

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a view in a .NET application. You use it in the same way you would use a table.

For example:

```
var result = from v in TestView select v;
```